# Prefilled device name in text field

Tags: input-fields, device

Sorry if there is already answer for this, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

In work we have recently disccused a behavior of our mobile application and we're not sure which way to go. Our app connects to a device with possibly long name (may differ) and user can rename this device if he wishes to do so or leave default name (always aligned to center).

Question is: How should we deal with this rename? Should the default name be grey and user can write his own name from the start (can mistake it for label and not change it at all - case 1), or the default name is black and user has to delete it first in order to write someting different (may be forced to delete a very long name - case 2)? Or some 3rd aproach?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use Option 2 (possibly with some instructive copy)**

*Graying out options increases the chance the input will be mistaken for one that has been disabled.*

Go with Option 2, which seems fine as it is, but if you test and find that users have issues, consider providing a way of clearing the input with a single click or tap.